# Is there a way to take a name that is formatted as Last Name, First Name and instead format it as first initial underscore last name in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My excel spreadsheet pulls a name from another tab and it is formatted as Smith, John. I have Vlookup formulas using that name so it can't be reformatted without making it a manual process. I have another tab with data that has the name formatted as j_smith, and I need a Vlookup formula for this tab to populate in the same area. I'm wondering if there is a formula I can use to turn Smith, John into j_smith so I can avoid having to type the abbreviations out manually for everyone since there are close to 500 names.

Comment: are the first and last name in the same cell or two different cells?

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: This is definitely achievable by a variety of formulae, but it would be good to see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=LOWER(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,1)&"_"&LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Lee you are the man!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of answers. Some easier than others.
I would probably use a combination of LEFT, MID and FIND functions.
You can always create a string using &.

- MID(string, starting point, and the number of characters.)

  - so if you want the 4th character from cell A1, you would use =MID(A1, 4, 1).

The problem is, you don't know which character to start with. So we combine this with FIND.

- FIND(string to search, what to find)

  - You do know you want the character after the space so =FIND(A1, " ")+1 would put you on the 1st letter of the 1st name.
    Use the FIND in place of 4 in the MID function above to get the 1st name initial.

For the last name, you could use the LEFT function.

- LEFT(string of text, number of character.)

  - Again, you don't know how long the last name is, but the FIND function will give you where the space is.

And we can always put things together using &.

- ="Hello" & " " & "world"

The ending result should look something like:

- =MID(A1, FIND(A1, " ")+1, 1) & "_" & LEFT(A1, FIND(A1, " "))